# yii Csrf Token cookies, Why Transfer to Post?

Tags: php, security, cookies, yii, csrf

Bad English:

Maybe I misunderstood how the Csrf, but why should it pass in the POST request, if it is in a cookie and can be taken from there.

If it is not safe, why not?
Why then it it the cookie is transmitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii would create a cookie with CSRF token and whenever the form is submitted it will compare the CSRF token in the cookie with the CSRF token in the from.